# How to add expo-google-fonts to global stylesheet

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fonts, expo

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@expo-google-fonts/poppins, and their example only shows how to load the fonts for the file that you'll be adding Text components to, and styling each component with the fontFamily. However, I have a global stylesheet, and I want to put the fonts there, instead of adding styling to every single Text component on each Screen.

This is the setup for the global stylesheet:

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export const globalStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fdfdfd",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
primaryButtonText: {
    color: "#fdfdfd",
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: "Poppins_100Thin",
  },
  secondaryButtonText: {
    color: "#228ee7",
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: "Poppins_100Thin",
  },
});
```

How do I add the fonts here without errors? I tried importing a fonts.js file and got errors with that too (tried to extract the font definition & importing logic from their example):

```
import {
  useFonts,
  Poppins_100Thin,
  Poppins_100Thin_Italic,
  Poppins_200ExtraLight,
  Poppins_200ExtraLight_Italic,
  Poppins_300Light,
  Poppins_300Light_Italic,
  Poppins_400Regular,
  Poppins_400Regular_Italic,
  Poppins_500Medium,
  Poppins_500Medium_Italic,
  Poppins_600SemiBold,
  Poppins_600SemiBold_Italic,
  Poppins_700Bold,
  Poppins_700Bold_Italic,
  Poppins_800ExtraBold,
  Poppins_800ExtraBold_Italic,
  Poppins_900Black,
  Poppins_900Black_Italic,
} from "@expo-google-fonts/poppins";

export default function PoppinsFont() {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Poppins_100Thin,
    Poppins_100Thin_Italic,
    Poppins_200ExtraLight,
    Poppins_200ExtraLight_Italic,
    Poppins_300Light,
    Poppins_300Light_Italic,
    Poppins_400Regular,
    Poppins_400Regular_Italic,
    Poppins_500Medium,
    Poppins_500Medium_Italic,
    Poppins_600SemiBold,
    Poppins_600SemiBold_Italic,
    Poppins_700Bold,
    Poppins_700Bold_Italic,
    Poppins_800ExtraBold,
    Poppins_800ExtraBold_Italic,
    Poppins_900Black,
    Poppins_900Black_Italic,
  });

  return fontsLoaded;
}
```

I tried doing this and adding `import PoppinsFont from "./fonts";` to the global stylesheet, and it did not work to import or load the fonts.

I know I can probably figure out adding a ttf file to the assets folder, but at this point, I really want to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I imported the fonts & put the useFonts in my App.js file. Now it works.